# How do I show a progressive number such as "Item 1 of termName", "Item 2 of termName"?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary with 4 taxonomy terms. There is a content type with a taxonomy reference field for that vocabulary.

I have a view that is pulling a list of all these nodes on a page. My design calls for the list to display to which taxonomy term the nodes belong, along with a progressive number.

> [image: screenshot]

Each node shows *Issue #*, where the progressive number shows which node was created first for that taxonomy term.

I thought being able to use tokens in view fields would help, but it seems it isn't currently possible, reading [Provide Field item that supports Text Filters](https://www.drupal.org/node/2037473).

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this without writing custom code?

I saw [Node count for taxonomy terms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/views-and-node-count-for-taxonomy-terms), but that's about showing a node count, while I want to show a progressive number.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you can set the format to html ordered list and group by the tag, but that will number the items automatically as in a standard ordered list with no control of the placement or prefixing with "Issue #". See [Number items in a grouped view, resetting counter with each group](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39152/number-items-in-a-grouped-view-resetting-counter-with-each-group), for example.

I think the views_php module with some custom coding could possibly work. I'll admit I have difficulties in getting parameters to reset effectively at times, but perhaps your mileage will vary.